# Python Generate Create Table

Tags: python

I have a table in which all the 120 fields have got type varchar(75). I have coded like this.

```
sql = "create table " + tableName + "("
for i in range(len(flds)):
    if i == len(flds) - 1:
        sql += flds[i] + " varchar(75))"
    else:
        sql += flds[i] + " varchar(75), "
```

Is it possible to get a one-liner for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's use `join` so we don't need the commas and `if`. And, while we're at it, we can just loop over `flds` instead of `range(len(flds))`:

```
columns = []
for fld in flds:
    columns.append(fld + " varchar(75)"
```

Of course this means we have to add the `)` on at the end:

```
sql += ', '.join(columns) + ')'
```

Now we can turn that loop into a comprehension:

```
columns = (fld + " varchar(75)" for fld in flds)
```

And now, we can inline that into the `join`:

```
sql += ', '.join(fld + " varchar(75)" for fld in flds) + ')'
```

And now, we have two lines that can obviously be combined into one:

```
sql = "create table " + tableName + "(" + ', '.join(fld + " varchar(75)" for fld in flds) + ')'
```

But that's way over 80 characters, so probably better to write it as two lines anyway. I'd probably do it like this:

```
columns = ', '.join(fld + " varchar(75)" for fld in flds)
sql = "create table " + tableName + "(" + columns + ")"
```

And finally, let's use an f-string instead of concatenating with `+`, which makes things only a little shorter, but a lot more readable.

```
columns = ', '.join(f'{fld} varchar(75)' for fld in flds)
sql = f'create table {tableName} ({columns})'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` with `format`:

```
v = "create table {} ({} varchar(75));".format(tableName, " varchar(75), ".join(flds))
```